# PHP Union Types with default value

Tags: php, union-types

I wanted to implement methods with union-type dependencies for the argument like so:

```
public function example(string|array $value = false){
    $data  = $value? $value : $this->otherValue;
}
```

but it's triggering an error

```
 Cannot use bool as the default value for parameter $value of type array|string.
```

I looked through the documentation but there is no mention of this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So if you expect only `string or array` - why you pass `bool`? Either add `|false` or `|bool` to argument definition.

Comment: @u_mulder You are absolutely right. I will delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new type for other type hint:

```php
<?php

class a{
    public function example(string|array|bool $value = false){
        $data  = $value? $value : $this->otherValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: While the answer is technically correct it is wrong as you (and OP) should understand the implications as either `false` (bool) is allowed (then your answer is correct and typehint union should be corrected) or not, then the `false` should be removed as it is invalid default value based on type hint.